# Cant Login to Cpanel After installing

Tags: centos

I have installed Cpanel on a CentOS by these commands :

1. cd /home
2. wget -N http://layer1.cpanel.net/latest
3. sh latest
4. /usr/local/cpanel/cpkeyclt

After that i lose GUI of CentOS , then i go to webpage of Cpanel but my root password doesn't work ether and then i have check the ssh connection to that server , after entering the root password i get : Access Denied .
I stuck , Please Help .
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by reinstalling CentOS and WHM but you should make sure your ssh works fine before installing WHM .

Hope it Help .